# Company behaving very oddly (and rudely) after phone interview

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

In August 2013 I've applied for what I can only describe as the job I've been dreaming of for the last 20 years. 
It should be noted that this is a big and respected company, but it is on the other side of the world.

On October 2013 I was granted a phone interview, which I thought went alright, and that's when the trouble began.

First of all, despite their promises to be in touch by the end of the following week, I haven't heard anything until I contacted them about it. I was then informed that my candidacy is being temporarily suspended because I'd require a work visa, which I can only apply for in April, and which I can only start using the following October, and therefore they will be contacting me in 2014 should the position still be open.

Fast forward to March 2014, when I decided to contact them about it ahead of time for safety's sake. The person who had previously informed me about the visa stuff has ignored both emails I sent, and after I emailed another person in HR (the one who set up my phone interview), somebody else emailed me to say that there has been a mistake, the deadline for the visa application was in January, and there's nothing else to do until 2015.
I've emailed this person twice with further questions about this, but received no reply.

Two weeks later I gave up and once again emailed the person who had set up the phone interview, who apologized profusely and promised to contact both the other people the very same day and have them contact me and explain everything.

This was the last contact and it was 8 days ago.

Now, while I don't think anyone has ever explicitly said that I passed the phone interview, I've said at least 3 times that I assumed as much (considering what else was said) and nobody corrected me or commented on it. I've definitely answered correctly all the questions on the interview, and it should be mentioned that the job description and requirements look like they were copied off of my CV. And the position, by the way, is still open.

The question: what should I do? What *can* I do? I sure wouldn't want to give up the job I've dreamed about my entire life just because their HR department is horribly unprofessional, but I have no idea what my status is, nor what can be done about it.

Comment: Where exactly have they been rude?  It sounds like they are not interested in moving on to the next stage.  If they were interested you would have started the application process so everything was ready for the submission date.

Comment: If you indicated that you think they didn't reject you at this stage, and nobody reacted with positive, encouraging comments, I would see that as a very polite - but pretty clear - way to let you know that you already have been rejected. Basically, they gave you some time to accept the rejection without too much distress; They just want to technically reject you. Nobody wants you to **feel** rejected!

Answer (score 8):

As a job applicant, you can't make a company hire you, nor can you make them reply promptly or professionally.

If you're at their mercy for the work visa as well, then you can contact them occasionally to find out the next steps (providing the job is still open), but you risk annoying them if you contact them too often.

If you can get the work visa without them, then I recommend you research ways to do so without their help, and try to get that.  That still won't make them hire you, but it can remove one of the barriers.

Other than that, all you can do is wait.  Their timetable can be affected by internal processes you don't know about, people taking leave for various reasons, budgeting issues, and a lot of other reasons that have nothing to do with you, other than it makes you wait longer.

The other thing to do is to apply for different jobs.  Dream jobs can be nightmare jobs once you are really in them -- from the outside you really can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

You best chance would be to directly connect to the hiring manager. It's possible that HR bungled the hiring and VISA process and are just not on the ball enough. If the hiring manager is strongly interested, he/she can rattle some HR cages and can get things moving. If not, nothing you can do will make any difference you should focus elsewhere, which could include a different position at the same company.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, this kind of attitude is pretty normal. HR at companies can typically ignore your application outright, interview you and never get back to you, or otherwise simply waste your time. It also happened to me to apply for a job that was a perfect match for me, and then never even hear from them, and two years later they are still looking for people in the same position. And since the ball is in their court, they can pretty much do what they like.

In my view, this reflects very badly on the company (or at least HR, but that also reflects on the company as a whole). It tells me that there is something very wrong with it. And even if it might seem like your dream job, you really don't know what it's like until you actually work there - in which case there's always a chance that you might be sorely disappointed.

So what I suggest is that you take note of their unprofessional attitude and take your skills to someone else who can actually appreciate them. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Clearly they didn't think you were a perfect match or you would have heard from them. There is nothing unprofessional in only contacting the people you are actually interested in hiring. There is nothing unprofessional in not continuing to stay in contact with people you have determined through the interview process that you are not intetrested in. It is unprofessional to expect a company to do things the way you want when it is not in the company's best interest.

Comment: It is unprofessional to leave a candidate waiting for feedback. Simple etiquette dictates that they at least send you an answer within a reasonable amount of time, no matter the outcome.

Comment: that is so laughable. In over 30 years in the work force I have had exactly 1 company tell me the result if I wasn't chosen. It is not in the company's best interest to have that conversation.

Comment: That doesn't make it a good attitude to adopt. It's not all about the company you know. Employment (or even prospective employment) is a two-way relationship and most companies unfortunately make the mistake of ignoring the element of mutual respect and give-and-take. I haven't been in the work force as long as you have, but I've worked in both types of companies, and know the difference very well.

Comment: @HLGEM "It is not in the company's best interest to have that conversation" - isn't it? I can't speak for the net benefit, but I can certainly see the advantage of letting a candidate know. They send a courtesy e-mail to let you know you weren't chosen, and perhaps even some generic tips to make you a better fit. You don't get a bad opinion about them. When you'd fit better into a role there, you reapply. Or you recommend a friend do so. Either way, they stand to gain a good employee in the future.

Comment: @Gigi - Depending on the part of the world this company is in. They are unlikely to provide a specific reason for not selecting somebody because of the laws that are in place. I agree with `HLGEM` its not unprofessional to explain the reason you didn't select somebody.  Actually it is all about the company, working for a company is all about what you can do for the company, the company then will compensate that person for doing so.

Comment: @Ramhound - Your last sentence is contradictory - read it again.

Comment: @Gigi - I don't believe its contradictory.  The pay is to get the person to do something for the company.  Having mutual respect doesn't change the foundation the worker/employeer relationship is built on.   The employeer exchanges a good so the employee will perform a service.

Comment: @gigi I agree with your utopic point of view, and will defend that it is "moraly right". However HLGEM and Ramhound have the "practical reality" on their side. In any case, not telling someone who is waiting what was the interview's outcome is unprofessional. Period. Common behavior does not make it any more professional, guys.

Comment: I believe a company should tell anyone that at least interviewed that they did not get the job.